# NameError: name 'getTempo' is not defined

Tags: python

i'm getting an error defining function "getTempo" and i don't know why... Thanks for the help.

example:

```
L=[Musica("aerossol",4.9),Musica("lua",5.3),Musica("monte",3.2),Musica("rita",4.7)];getTempo("lua",L)
```

should give:

lua:5.3

5.3

---

```
class Musica:
    def __init__(self,nome,tempo):
        self.nome=nome
        self.tempo=tempo
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.nome+":"+str(self.tempo)

    def getTempo(nomeMusica,ListaMusicas):
        if ListaMusicas==[]:
            print ("Inexistente")
        else:
            meio=len(ListaMusicas)//2
            print (ListaMusicas[meio])
            A = [i[0] for i in ListaMusicas]
            B = [i[1] for i in ListaMusicas]

            if nomeMusica==A[meio]:
                print (B[meio])
            elif nomeMusica<A[meio]:
                return getTempo(nomeMusica,ListaMusicas[:meio])
            else:
                return getTempo(nomeMusica,ListaMusicas[(meio+1):])
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, please post the error you're getting.

Answer (score -1):

In `python`, unlike languages like `Java` or `C++`, instance attributes and methods must be accessed on the instance, so you must write `self.getTempo` in order for `getTempo` to resolve.

EDIT - Selective Reading Failure

You also need to make sure that all method definitions include an argument for the class instance itself, which will be the first argument passed. By convention, this is the `self` argument, but it can be any name you choose. Here is the modified function definition:

```
def getTempo(self, nomeMusica,ListaMusicas): # Changed
    if ListaMusicas==[]:
        print ("Inexistente")
    else:
        meio=len(ListaMusicas)//2
        print (ListaMusicas[meio])
        A = [i[0] for i in ListaMusicas]
        B = [i[1] for i in ListaMusicas]

        if nomeMusica==A[meio]:
            print (B[meio])
        elif nomeMusica<A[meio]:
            return self.getTempo(nomeMusica,ListaMusicas[:meio]) # Changed
        else:
            return self.getTempo(nomeMusica,ListaMusicas[(meio+1):]) # Changed
```

Comment: sorry i didn't understand, what am i suposed to do then?

Comment: @diogo: Use `self.getTempo` instead of `getTempo`

Comment: Please see my edits. Your function definition was missing a few more details and would not have worked even after that.

Comment: Do you mean for `getTempo` to be a method of `Musica` or a function called on a `list` of `Musica` instances?

Comment: @mobiusklein a method of Musica

Comment: Then based on your example usage snippet, you need to call it from an instance of `Musica`:L=[Musica("aerossol",4.9),Musica("lua",5.3),Musica("monte",3.2),Musica("rita",4.7)], L[0].getTempo("lua", L)

Comment: @mobiusklein this is embarrassing, i wanted to say a function called on a list of Musica instances, sorry

Comment: Okay, in that case, your original implementation is okay, you just have to take the function out of the class, so un-indent it. That way it becomes a "free function".

Comment: okay i managed to resolve the problem... it was as easy as not using the A and B and using ListaMusica[meio].nome or ListaMusica[meio].tempo

Comment: after that i got error at the output it was  meio=len(ListaMusicas)//2, it should be  meio=(len(ListaMusicas)-1)//2